# Using 3D HTML5 models in Android native app

Tags: java, android, html, 3d, native

I'm asking myself if there is a way to integrate some 3D HTML5 models inside some native Android application?

The idea would be to be able to easily switch from Java to HTML5 and from HTML5 to Java inside the app.

Is it technically possible to do such a thing?